# Sending list of integers to REST API throws 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm experimenting with reactjs and .net core web api, and I'm trying to send simple list of integer to the rest api. Throught postman I did it without any issues, but when I try to do it from my react js code I'm getting 415 error in a console:

This is how my method on the API looks:

```
   // DELETE api/SiteUsers/delete
   [HttpPost("delete")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteSiteUsers(DeleteValuesDto deleteValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
            
        return NoContent();
   }
```

Here is how my DeleteValuesDto looks like:

[image]

On the frontend I made simple method which should make an api call to rest api:

```
 const handleDelete = async () => {
    var deleteValues = {
      values: selectedRows,
    };
    await deleteSiteUser(deleteValues);
  };
```

Here is my `deleteSiteUser` method on frontend:

```
export const deleteSiteUser = (deleteValues) => {
  console.log('deleteValues', deleteValues);
  return axiosWrapper.request({
    url: `/SiteUsers/delete`,
    method: 'POST',
    deleteValues,
  });
};
```

Here are the results of console log:

[image]

I thought this would be very simple, but I find out it isn't actually :/

Comment: Are you posting this as form data?

Comment: @Marco No.. I'm just sending it as a classic post request, not adding it to form

Comment: I can only imagine, this is related to your axios request. Try setting it as `data`: `axiosWrapper.request({ url: `/SiteUsers/delete`, method: 'POST', data: deleteValues,
  });` as per the documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: @Marco That is right mate! I just red it! But thanks for help. So you could write an answer with little bit of explanations so I could accept it as anwer! Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the data in the named `data` property as per the documentation (https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

```
export const deleteSiteUser = (deleteValues) => {
  console.log('deleteValues', deleteValues);
  return axiosWrapper.request({
    url: '/SiteUsers/delete',
    method: 'POST',
    data: deleteValues,
  });
};
```

If you are not setting the data property, the payload is empty. The most likely outcome of this is, that the `Conent-Type` header is not set and thus Asp.Net cannot decide how to parse the request body and then throws that error.  You could just check that in your developer console in Chrome, then set the `data` property and check the Content-Type header for that reqeust as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the IDs in an object that has a `values` field, but your endpoint is expecting a plain array.

Instead of wrapping `selectedRows` like you do with `deleteValues`, just pass it through directly.

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
    await deleteSiteUser(selectedRows);
  };
```

Comment: My endpoint is expecting just an deleteValues which is an object, and inside is an array? so this change that you recommend requires to me to modify API endpoint also ? right ?

Comment: Sorry my bad I misunderstood the question. However maybe you need to capitalise `Values`? I'm not sure though.

Comment: I've tried capitalizing "Values" on frontend and few other things, but it's not working and I'm not sure why :(